# Writing a method that itterates over a Map, looks for Object entries that contain a value, adds this Object to a new set then returns that set

Tags: java, loops, set, maps

I am learning how to code in Java and struggling with this concept.
I need to write a method that takes a char argument which exists within the Objects that are in a map.

It needs to return a currently non existing Set of Objects that contain this char value as a new Set after iterating over the map to find these objects.

The following is my current code which doesn't get my desired outcome, I believe the problem is in the if statement. I have done lots of different combinations of `equals()` and `containsValue` on the object and map and cannot seem to get it to return true.

```
public Set findObj(char aChar)
{
    Set<String> objSet = new HashSet();

    for (Object Obj: map1.values())
    {  
       if (map1.values().contains(aChar))
       {
           //if true add to objSet
       }
    }

    return objSet;
}
```

If it helps the Map is

```
Map<String,Obj> map1= new HashMap<>();
```

and the Object is created by a class and contains a 3 variables, 2 string and one being the char value I am trying to find within each iteration of the map.

Comment: It would help, if you add how your map is defined. E.g. what type are the values there, is that realy of Type `Object` ?

Comment: If you call the `values()` method on a map you'll get a `Collection` back which has no method `containsValue()`. You probably wanted to call the `contains()` method there?

Comment: Question seems bit off
containsValue can check the value for entitr value list
no matter how many time you add same object to Set it will contain only 1 single object

Comment: You iterate over all values and then call `if (map1.values().containsValue(aChar))` - seems fishy.

Comment: I might be misunderstanding whats required, the main out come needs to be an unordered set of Objects. I thought that's what I needed to do to get the desired outcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are correct the problem is mainly in your if statement, since you're iterating over the objects in the map, you should check if **the current object** contains the string not whether or not the map as a whole contains it

```
public Set findObj(char aChar) {
    Set<String> objSet = new HashSet();
    for (Object c : map1.values()) {
        if (c.toString().indexOf(aChar) >= 0) {
            //if true add to objSet
        }
    }
    return objSet;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This gets the desired outcome, just had to add <String> after Hashset as I was getting the "uses unchecked or unsafe operations." error when compiling.